# Probit/Logit Model - How to find the parameter $\beta$

Tags: logit, probit

I am confused on how to calculate the beta in a probit/logit model

Probit Model
$P(Y_i=1)=\Phi(X'\beta)$

Logit Model: $P(Y_i=1)=e^{X'\beta}/(1+e^{X'\beta})$

These  formula's are great but how do I calculate the beta's in the model? What is a proper estimator for beta hat?

Comment: You are asking how we estimate $\beta$ given a set of data? This might be of interest: http://www.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/21121_Chapter_15.pdf

Comment: They don't have closed solutions except in a few specific cases, e.g. X is a binary variable: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178584/how-to-estimate-coefficients-of-logistic-model/178589#178589

Comment: The title contains the most remarkable spelling of "probabilities" that has ever appeared on this site!

Comment: ^Ha! Thank you. I just noticed the typo. That is fascinating spelling.

Comment: Hi P.Windridge. Thanks for your answer. So according to your solution, you do have a closed form if the x is binary. If it is not your saying it has no closed form solution. Is there a manual/textbook that goes into detail in finding the numeric solution. What technique is being used. I am very fascinated by this problem. Thank you again.

Comment: For the record, the spelling was Probobiabilites

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to answer your question, as you do not provide the background you have. Here is a general answer.

---

You want to find $\mathbb{P}[Y_i = 1 | X_i]$ when you have a bunch of data that comes from the same distribution, that is, the result ($Y_i$) is influenced the same way by the inputs ($X_i$) of each sample you have. Read more: [I.I.D. (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables).

You know $X_i$ and $Y_i$ for your samples, and you want to find a function that maps the inputs to the outputs as close as possible. This is what the probit/logit models are doing, and they have a parameter $\beta$ to dictate the influence of the different input variables. To find the best $\beta$, we have first to define what *the best* is.

In linear regression models, the *best* model is often defined by the model that has the best $R^2$ measure with the output, or the one that has the smallest [Mean Squared Error (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error). In classification tasks, a common measure is the [Logistic loss (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification#Logistic_loss).

The value of the loss function is $L(y, f(x,\beta))$ where $L$ is the loss function, $x,y$ the input and output variables, and $\beta$ are the parameters of your model. It is a comparison of your model with the real result $y$, and gives you a metric to evaluate your model. You want to have the lowest error with respect to $\beta$,
$$\hat{\beta} = \arg \min_{\beta} L(y,f(x,\beta))$$
Depending on your model and cost function, you can equate the derivative to 0 and compute the $\beta$ that makes it possible based on the data. In the case of the transformed models you are interested about, this is not possible, as as mentionned in the comments, no *closed solution* exists. However, you can come very close to the optimal solution by using [gradient descent (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). The idea is that the derivative of the function at a certain $\beta$ will point to the direction of highest increase in the cost function with respect to $\beta$, and if you go in the other direction, your $\beta$ will improve and the error will lower. As long as your cost function is *convex*, you will fill a global minimum, the optimal $\beta$.

---

How to find the parameters of the logistic regression is the introduction of a lot of books and classes in Machine learning. For a more specific answer, I'd advise looking at

- [Elements of Statistical Learning, by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman (Book website, free download)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)
- Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, by Christopher Bishop.
- Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective, by Kevin Murphy.
- [Andrew Ng's Mooc](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)
- Any other book/mooc/class on statistical/machine learning will introduce this concept.

You can also take a look at questions on a similar topic on CrossValidated,

- [What is the difference between linear regression and logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression)
- [Solving for regression parameters in closed form vs. gradient descent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23128/solving-for-regression-parameters-in-closed-form-vs-gradient-descent)